# Start solr server in terminal works but not in cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd, solr

I'm trying to start a Solr server in cloudmode by writing this command in my:

```
cmd ./bin/solr start -c -p 8983 -s example/cloud/node1/solr
```

It works when I do it in the terminal (Windows PowerShell) but not via cmd. It made me curious why it is this way. I have not find any solutions on the internet.

The error message I get in CMD is:

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Does anyone have any idea what can cause this problem? And yes I'm in the right dir and have started cmd as administrator.

I tried using the command

```
./bin/solr start -c -p 8983 -s example/cloud/node1/solr
```

In both admin and not admin mode of CMD. I tried without the dot as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *PowerShell* allows *interchangeable* use of `\` and `/` as the path separator.
- `cmd.exe` does *not*: it only recognizes `\` in program paths, as well as in its internal commands such as `dir`.

Therefore:

```bash
.\bin\solr start -c -p 8983 -s example/cloud/node1/solr
```

Note that I'm assuming that the specific CLI you're calling, `solr`, *does* accept `/`, which is implied by the fact that the original command works as-is in PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you this was the soloution! :)